# PHP if statement using !empty() not properly checking existing variables

Tags: php, angularjs, json, if-statement

I've come across a weird problem which I can't seem to debug properly.
I'm currently creating a registration form using AngularJS and JSON requests to PHP files. Here is an example of input data that I used for debugging.

[image: Registration form]

Now the request sent clearly contains the following data as seen by debugging the JSON response.

[image: Debug 1]
[image: Debug 2]

Now for some reason, `$response['debug-two']` or `$response['debug-info-two']` does not get added to the responding JSON, even if all the fields required are `!empty()` or `true`. Also, neither is `$reponse['empty-fields']`. Therefor it must really boil down to the empty fields if-statement, but I can't seem to understand or figure out why, since all the fields are set as of `$response['debug-info']`.

```
# Prevent XSRF
if ($session->checkXSRF()) {
    # Get POST data
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $fullname = $data->fullname;
    $email = $data->email;
    $birthday = $data->bithday;
    $password1 = $data->password1;
    $password2 = $data->password2;
    $agreement1 = $data->agreement1;
    $agreement2 = $data->agreement2;

    $response['debug'] = $data;
    $response['debug-info'] = $fullname.$email.$birthday.$password1.$password2.$agreement1.$agreement2;

    # Check if empty fields
    if ( (!empty($fullname)) && (!empty($email)) && (!empty($birthday)) && (!empty($password1)) && (!empty($password2)) && ($agreement1) ) {
        $response['debug-two'] = $data;
        $response['debug-info-two'] = $fullname.$email.$birthday.$password1.$password2.$agreement1.$agreement2;
    } else {
        # All fields are required
        $reponse['empty-fields'] = true;
    }
} else {
    # XSRF Error detected
    $response['xsrf-invalid'] = true;
}

# Return JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: There's a typo in this line; `$reponse['empty-fields'] = true;` - should be `$response['empty-fields'] = true;` (You missed the 's'). What are you actually trying to check with the if statement?

Comment: @thebluefox Oh, yes, that made the empty-fields go off, but why does it do that? When all the fields are !empty() and agreement1 is true?

Comment: Do a little debugging and see which of those expressions is false. `var_dump((!empty($fullname)) . ' && ' .(!empty($email)) . ' && ' .(!empty($birthday)) . ' && ' .(!empty($password1)) . ' && ' .(!empty($password2)) . ' && ' .($agreement1) );`

Comment: @thebluefox Found the problem, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of typo's that are causing you issues.

The first is in `$birthday = $data->bithday;` - you missed the 'r' from 'birthday'

Secondly, in `$reponse['empty-fields'] = true;` you missed the 's' from 'response'.

```
# Prevent XSRF
if ($session->checkXSRF()) {
    # Get POST data
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $fullname = $data->fullname;
    $email = $data->email;
    $birthday = $data->birthday;
    $password1 = $data->password1;
    $password2 = $data->password2;
    $agreement1 = $data->agreement1;
    $agreement2 = $data->agreement2;

    $response['debug'] = $data;
    $response['debug-info'] = $fullname.$email.$birthday.$password1.$password2.$agreement1.$agreement2;

    # Check if empty fields
    if ( (!empty($fullname)) && (!empty($email)) && (!empty($birthday)) && (!empty($password1)) && (!empty($password2)) && ($agreement1) ) {
        $response['debug-two'] = $data;
        $response['debug-info-two'] = $fullname.$email.$birthday.$password1.$password2.$agreement1.$agreement2;
    } else {
        # All fields are required
        $response['empty-fields'] = true;
    }
} else {
    # XSRF Error detected
    $response['xsrf-invalid'] = true;
}

# Return JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```